# Extend existing PostgreSQL type

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-function, composite-types

Is it possible to extend an existing datatype in PostgreSQL? Essentially, I want the equivalent of this TypeScript but in SQL:

```js
interface Meeting {
  id: number;
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  description: string;
}

interface ServiceHour extends Meeting {
  total: number;
  hours: number;
}
```

Because I have a function that returns all the columns from a `meetings` table and then the additional two `total` and `hours` columns that are computed at query time. Here's what that function looks like:

```sql
create or replace function user_hours(org_id text, user_id text)
returns table (like meeting_instances)
as $$
select (sum(hours) over (order by _.instance_time)) total, * from (
  select
    extract(epoch from ((meeting_instances.time).to - (meeting_instances.time).from)) / 60 / 60 as hours, 
    meeting_instances.*
  from meeting_instances inner join relation_people on relation_people.meeting = meeting_instances.id
  where relation_people.user = user_id
  and meeting_instances.org = org_id
  and meeting_instances.instance_time <= current_date
) as _;
$$
language sql stable;
```

And right now, I'm getting a type mismatch error because `table (like meeting_instances)` isn't the same as a table with the `meeting_instances` columns **and** the two new `hours` and `total` columns. What I want to be able to do is something like this (obviously the syntax below doesn't actually exist... but I'm not sure if there's another way to do this with a similar shorthand syntax):

```sql
returns table (total float, hours float, meeting_instances.*)
returns table (total float, hours float) intersect (like meeting_instances)
returns table (total float, hours float) extends (like meeting_instances)
```

My current workaround is to create a view and then have that function simply query that view and return the view's type.

Comment: Start by disclosing your Postgres version and the actual definition of the involved Postgres tables (`CREATE TABLE ...`). Seems like you have multiple layers of nested composite types. You *can* do that in Postgres. Doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You can nest them, but can you extend them (like a `LIKE` clause on a table definition)?

Comment: @Bergi: No, you can't. Not in a `RETURNS` clause, not anywhere else. Actually `RETURNS (LIKE tbl)` is not even documented syntax. I am in the process of unravelling the multiple layers in an answer ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, that's what I thought. But I don't see why it seems that the OP has "*multiple layers of nested composite types*"? Looking forward to your answer :-)

Comment: `meeting_instances.time` is already a nested composite type. And we don't know how deep the rabbit hole goes.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ah, I had missed that. It might also be a function call tough. We need to see the table/type definitions indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To your **core question**:

> Is it possible to extend an existing datatype?

**No**, not possible. Not in the `RETURNS` clause of `CREATE FUNCTION`, not anywhere else in PostgreSQL up to version 14.

You can return a field of composite type, plus additional fields of any type. But that's subtly different:

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_hours_plus( ...)
  RETURNS TABLE (my_meeting meeting_instances, hours numeric, total numeric) ...
```

Calling that function with:

```
SELECT * FROM user_hours_plus('a', 'b');
```

Returns a nested composite type as one of the return columns, like:

```
(1,"2017-01-03","2017-01-04", foo) | 123 | 345
```

To decompose the composite type, you *could* call with:

```
SELECT (my_meeting).*, hours, total FROM user_hours_plus('a', 'b');
```

But I wouldn't go there.

> My current workaround is to create a view and then have that function simply query that view and return the view's type.

Then just use the view. Don't create an additional function on top of it. Case closed.

**If** you actually meant to say:

> *... then use the row type of the view in the `RETURNS` clause of the function*

Then we are back to your question. [`CREATE VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) to (implicitly) register the extended row type is a valid option - especially since `SELECT *` is a convenient syntax shorthand for the case at had. But for starters,

```
RETURNS TABLE (LIKE meeting_instances)
```

... isn't documented syntax for [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). **Nobody should use it.** Might be removed without notice in one of the next versions.
The canonical, equivalent, documented syntax is:

```
RETURNS SETOF meeting_instances
```

<sub>`(LIKE some_table)` is documented syntax for [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). The `RETURNS` clause of `CREATE FUNCTION` currently supports the same, but it's not documented, so don't use it.</sub>

Back to your workaround with creating a `VIEW`. If you have no use for the `VIEW`, other than registering that extended row type, consider [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) instead. Unfortunately, `CREATE TYPE` does not allow `LIKE other_type` syntax, either. You have to spell out all columns (attributes) of the composite type. Like:

```sql
CREATE TYPE meeting_plus AS (
   id numeric
 , start date
 , "end" date
 , description text
 , total numeric
 , hours numeric
);
```

Then you can use:

```
RETURNS SETOF meeting_plus
```

Just like you wanted.

But for just the one function, I would use `RETURNS TABLE()` instead and spell out the return type:

```
RETURNS TABLE (
   id numeric
 , start date
 , "end" date
 , description text
 , total numeric
 , hours numeric)
```

Oh, and I wouldn't use "start" and "end" as identifiers in Postgres. Both are [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL. "end" is absolutely reserved in Postgres and must always be double-quoted.